# How to parse German dates which change format?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I am trying to parse the following dataframe

```
IN:
import pandas as pd
d = {'Tag': ['Tag 1', 'Tag 2'], 'Datum': ['07. März 1971', '29. Nov. 1970']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

OUT:   
  Tag          Datum
0  Tag 1  07. März 1971
1  Tag 2  29. Nov. 1970
```

I understand that I need to use **locale** to be able to specify the format:

```
import locale
```

and I have found multiple settings which I have tried out:

```
# locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, "german")
# locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'deu_deu')
# locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'de_DE')
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'de_DE.utf8')
```

But I do not find the correct code to use **to_dateime**:

```
 # df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Datum'])
 df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Datum'], format="%d. %b. %Y")
```

Is the problem connected to the fact that the German format does not have a consistent month format?
How to I use **to_datetime** here?

Comment: if I specify %b. I get an error with "März", if I specify %b I get an error with "Nov."

Comment: Sounds like you should do some preprocessing (remove such extraneous characters) first.

Comment: Just try-except both versions, or write code to distinguish between the two (e.g. using `re`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not an answer for `pd.to_datetime`, but there's another package [`dateparser`](https://pypi.org/project/dateparser/) which can handle dates in multiple languages.

```
import dateparser

df['Datum'] = df['Datum'].apply(dateparser.parse)
```

```
     Tag      Datum
0  Tag 1 1971-03-07
1  Tag 2 1970-11-29
```

Comment: ok, thanks. I somehow hoped to stay within in pandas as dateparser was not installed.